# How can I expose all available liquid methods for a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2, liquid

Several of my models have liquid methods defined, using:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  liquid_methods :created_at, :foo, :bar, :baz
end
```

How can I get a list of available methods for a model (in a hash or array, I suppose)? I'd like to output the list of available methods to users who use them in things like forum posts or email templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save yourself the unnecessary instantiation:

```
MyModel::LiquidDropClass.public_instance_methods - Liquid::Drop.public_instance_methods
# => [:foo, :bar, :baz] (or whatever your liquid methods are)
```

When you call `liquid_methods` on a model, liquid creates the `LiquidDropClass` class within your model's namespace, and it holds the liquid methods.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
MyModel.new.to_liquid.methods - Liquid::Drop.new.methods
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if it will have different behaviour concerning liquid methods, but you can do:

```
MyModel.methods
MyMethod.new.methods
```

Either way, on a class or on an instance, you can call `.methods` to get an array of symbols that are valid methods to use on that class or instance. You can then do things like `.methods.sort` or `.methods.sort_by` etc.

Comment: So, doing that, I get: `[333] liquid_methods(*arg1) Class (Module)`. MyModel.liquid_methods doesn't return anything. Suggestions?

Comment: This solution returns all methods, not just liquid methods.